# How do I close a view Window?

Tags: interface

I've read and seen all the questions and the directions say that you have to click and drag the tab used to create a new window over the window until an arrow appears and it will remove the view window. BUT I KEEP TRYING AND NOW I HAVE OVER TWENTY WINDOWS OPEN I NEEEEEDDDD HEEELLPPPP! can someone tag a youtube video or make a better description of how in hell im supposed to close these lol.

Comment: There is a youtube video linked in the answer in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit tricky, because to choose the window you want to close you'll have to first drag the cursor towards the neighboring window.
[image]
[image]

Otherwise you'll just duplicate the window.
[image]