# Setting Up A Minimal Sculpting Environment With An Image Area

Tags: interface

I want to sculpt in a minimal set up with a reference image loaded in another area. I will toggle views to change settings when needed. But, I'm having trouble with the steps to set this up.

I understand how to split areas in Blender. I also know how to hide areas with: 't', 'n' and 'shift+space'. I understand that F11 will give me full screen, getting rid of the window chrome. But, I'm having trouble combining these steps in a way that will create the minimal sculpting set up I have provided below. *I don't want the areas with the red x's. I only want the areas with the orange check marks.*

[image]

What steps will achieve this set-up?

Comment: Generally you have already written all the necessary tools for that - splitting / joining area, getting rid of Tools and Properties menu.. Shift+Space won't help here, unfortunately. The procedure is already in the answer, I can propose another solution - change screen layout to 3D View Full, make a copy of it (to backup), and split resulting full 3D View once. There set up a UV/Image editor. Save in User Prefs if needed.

Comment: Blender comes with full screen layout by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go: 

**1. Remove UV Screen** 

This may sound contradictory, but necessary to remove the timeline. Blender is weird like this and will only collapse a section if their is only one section spanning the width of it above it. Remember to collapse a section pull on those little three lines in the top corner[image: The start]
[image] 

**2. Collapse Timeline** 

Pull on the three corners in the 3d view as shown in the image.

[image: Collapsing Timeline] 

3.**Right Panel** 

Remember step one when we collapsed the UV screen to collapse the timeline? Well we have to do this again to collapse the right panel. First pull down then up as depicted in the image below to remove the outliner. 
[image: Remove right panel]

**4.Finishing up** 

Now, press <kbd>T</kbd> to close the tool panel. Next pull the top three corners of the 3d view toward the right panel to collapse it. To remove that top bar pull on the three lines below the info icon and pull down, then up. Finally, Pull the 3d view corner again to the left to open up another 3d view. You can change it to UV image editor by clicking the icon. 
[image: End Screen]

### **Further Reading**

[How to close view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows) 

[Arranging Areas - Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/areas.html#arranging) 

[Simple, Nice Explanation On BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40867/26541) 

[Great Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMBi1R7KB48)

Comment: This is a good answer, but after now understanding the answer I would agree this question is a duplicate. I did have one issue. I had to close that image view before I could get rid of the info area on top.