# How do i join 2 vertical windows?

Tags: interface

How do i join 2 vertical windows on a mac with blender 2.78c?
Seems to be getting harder and harder to accomplish!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21008/can-not-close-windows-in-interface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40866/how-do-i-close-a-view-window

Comment: @user3737772 there is nothing different on a mac or windows or linux... see above links they should work on your mac. If not, detail why they are not working.